# Return a class pointer to Java by JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

There is a existing class pointer in C++
How do i get this class pointer and converter to class in java by JNI

Class_A_B.cpp

```
Class ClassB
{
public:
    int funcA();
    int funcB();
}
Class ClassA
{
public:
    virtual void func(){B = new ClassB();};
    ClassB* B;
    ClassB* GetClassB(){return B;};
}
```

Jni_Class_A_B.cpp

```
ClassA TestClassA = new ClassA();

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_core_Android_getClassB(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{
    return (jobject)TestClassA->GetClassB();    // It will crash, how to converter class pointer to jobject?
}
```

GetClassB.java

```
public native ClassB getClassB();
public void TestFunction()
{
    ClassB B = getClassB();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to convert a pointer to a C++ native object (a "class pointer" as you put it) into a `jobject`.  Indeed, if you *could* do this, you would most likely hard-crash the JVM ... 'cos the Java GC would not be able to cope with the C++ object.

The best you could do would be to pass / return the C++ pointer to Java as a 32 or 64 bit integer, and then use another JNI call if the Java code needs to access the C++ object's state or call a method on it.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a existing class pointer in C++

No there isn't. There is a pointer to an *instance* of ClassB.

> How do i get this class pointer and converter to class in java by JNI

You can't. They aren't equivalent. A pointer to an instance of a C++ class can't be converted to a reference to a Java class.

In short your question doesn't make sense.